# Kotlin !! Operator usage makes code not clear

Tags: android, null, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I am writing a Kotlin application, I've been studying this language for a little bit and I noticed that to create a variable you have to explicitly define if it can be null and then you use the ? operator.

Now, my question. Sometimes I have to define a global variable (a Fragment in this case), so I need to make it null, because I cannot initialize it yet

In java I don't have this problem because the first thing I do after declaring it is initializing in the onCreate() like this

```
TurboFragment fragment = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    fragment = adapter.getCurrentFragment();
}
```

And then I can use it without syntax problems
In Kotlin is different, because I have to do like that

```
private var fragment: TurboFragment? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    ...

    fragment = adapter!!.currentFragment
    fragment!!.foo()
    var x = fragment!!.sampleInt
}
```

Now, every time I call an instance of fragment i have to use the null-safe **!!** operator. This makes my code a mess, because for every line I have at least one !! operator and it looks really unclear if it's so frequent, especially if you have 5 or more variables like that. 
Is there a way to simplify the code or the nature of this language is like that?

Comment: How about `private lateinit var fragment: TurboFragment` then? [(documentation)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [Late-Initialized Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables). They're intended for your use-case.

```
private lateinit var fragment: TurboFragment
```

However, you should keep in mind that accessing a `lateinit` property before it has been initialized throws an exception. That means you should use them only if you are absolutely sure, they **will** be initialized.

```
print(fragment)  // UninitializedPropertyAccessException is thrown
```